# How to prove "~(nat = False)", "~(nat = bool)" and "~(nat = True)" in coq

Tags: functional-programming, logic, coq, dependent-type, type-theory

The following two propositions are easy to prove.

```
Theorem nat_eq_nat : nat = nat.
Proof.
  trivial.
Qed.

Theorem True_neq_False : ~(True = False).
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros.
  symmetry in H.
  rewrite H.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

But when I tried to prove a slightly different proposition `~(nat = False)`, I found the rewrite tactic doesn't work. It reports

> Error: Refiner was given an argument "fun x : Set => x" of type "Set
>   -> Set" instead of "Set -> Prop".

So I tried to write a lemma.

```
Lemma Type_eq_prod : forall (a : Type) (b : Type), a = b -> (a -> b).
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite <- H.
  trivial.
Qed.

Theorem nat_neq_False : ~(nat = False).
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros.
  apply (Type_eq_prod nat False) in H.
  inversion H.
  apply 0. (*no subgoals left*)
```

All works fine until now. But when I tried to Qed it, it reported

```
Error: Illegal application (Type Error): 
The term "Type_eq_prod" of type "forall a b : Type, a = b -> a -> b"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "nat" : "Set"
 "False" : "Prop"
 "H" : "nat = False"
 "0" : "nat"
The 3rd term has type "nat = False" which should be coercible to
 "nat = False".
```

The following are another two propositions that make me stuck.

```
Theorem nat_neq_bool : ~(nat = bool).
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros.
Abort.

Theorem nat_neq_true : ~(nat = True).
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros.
Abort.
```

My questions are:

```
 1.Why the rewrite tactic doesn't work with proposition ~(nat = False).
 2.Why can't I Qed it when there is no subgoals.
 3.How to prove the aborted propositions above or is it possible to prove or prove the negates of them in coq.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The rewrite tactic doesn't work due to how Coq handles its universes, `Prop`, `Set` and `Type`. There is a notion of subsumption which allows one to use a `Prop` as if it were a `Set` or a `Type`. This is why you were allowed to write `nat = False` in the first place, since equality is only allowed between things of the same type. The problem is that, for Coq, `False : Prop` is different from `False : Set`. `not` is defined with `False : Prop`, which means that that rewrite will produce a mismatch, which explains the error message you got.

   Here are similar approaches that would work. Notice the explicit coercion to `Set`.

   ```
   Lemma nat_neq_False_2 : (nat = False) -> (False : Set).
   Proof.
     intros H.
     rewrite <- H.
     apply 0.
   Qed.

   Lemma nat_neq_False_3 : ~(nat = False).
   Proof.
     intros H.
     destruct (nat_neq_False_2 H).
   Qed.
   ```
2. When you write a proof using tactics, Coq is essentially building a proof term internally, but isn't really typechecking it. In this sense, it is a little bit like metaprogramming. Once you hit `Qed`, the term that was built by the tactic is sent to the typechecker to make sure it is OK. Most of the times, tactics produce proofs that are correct, but every once in a while one finds proofs that are not accepted, and your case is an example of that.

   The error message that was printed was not very clear, but one can get a better sense of what's happening by using the command `Set Printing All`, which causes Coq to print all terms and statements without notations and showing implicit arguments. This is what your error message becomes when doing that:

   ```
   Set Printing All.

   Lemma Type_eq_prod : forall (a : Type) (b : Type), a = b -> (a -> b).
   Proof.
     intros.
     rewrite <- H.
     trivial.
   Qed.

   Theorem nat_neq_False : ~(nat = False).
   Proof.
     unfold not.
     intros.
     apply (Type_eq_prod nat False) in H.
     inversion H.
     apply 0. (*no subgoals left*)
   Qed.


   (* Error: Illegal application (Type Error):  *)
   (* The term "Type_eq_prod" of type "forall a b : Type, @eq Type a b -> a -> b" *)
   (* cannot be applied to the terms *)
   (*  "nat" : "Set" *)
   (*  "False" : "Prop" *)
   (*  "H" : "@eq Set nat False" *)
   (*  "O" : "nat" *)
   (* The 3rd term has type "@eq Set nat False" which should be coercible to *)
   (*  "@eq Type nat False". *)
   ```

   There, we can see that the problem is that there is again a universe mismatch: one equality is in `Type`, while the other is in `Set`. There are several ways one can fix this; the easiest is probably to change your first theorem to:

   ```
   Lemma Type_eq_prod : forall (a : Set) (b : Set), a = b -> (a -> b).
   ```
3. Both propositions are provable in Coq. In the base theory of Coq, the only way one can show that simple types such as `nat` and `bool` are different is by cardinality arguments. Thus, `nat <> bool` because `bool` has only two elements, whereas `nat` has more than that. Thus, by showing that `bool` has two elements, one can rewrite the equality `nat = bool` to find out that `nat` should also have two elements, and then exploit that to get a contradiction. A similar argument would show that `nat <> True`.

Comment: But how to show that bool has two elements? And if the two sets are nat and positive which have equal elements in theory, then how to prove nat <> positive?

Comment: Showing that bool has only two elements is easy: one can prove a statement such as `exists b1 b2 : bool, forall b3 : bool, b3 = b1 \/ b3 = b2.` by doing `exists true. exists false. intros []; auto.`. It is not possible, however, to show that `nat <> positive` in Coq. As it turns out, this is independent from the theory, meaning that it is safe to add `nat = positive` and `nat <> positive` as axioms separately.